# Absolute anchor tag vs anchor tag with absolute span

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I've seen two ways of stretching a link over a card/container/div/whatever to make the entire thing clickable.

The first option positions the `<a>` tag as an absolute element.

The second option leaves the `<a>` untouched and places an absolute `span` tag inside - causing the `a` to expand and fill the container.

Is there an actual reason for one over the other?

```css
.card {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.absolute-a, .absolute-span {
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <a href="#" class="absolute-a">
    Using absolute on anchor
  </a>
</div> 

<div class="card">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="absolute-span">
      Using absolute span
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand that What's your question exactly?

Comment: Both option work.
My question is if there's something a11y related on why would you use one over the other.

Comment: Oh yes! I think this doesn't have many differences, but the first case is shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an accessibility perspective, the main difference I could pick up between using an absolute anchor tag versus using an absolute span tag is the visible focus rectangle that appears when either element has focus.

For the absolute anchor card, the visible focus rectangle covers the entire card:
[image: Card using absolute link styling]

For the absolute span card, the visible focus rectangle doesn't appear (Chrome), or is very small (Firefox):
[image: Card using absolute span styling]

It's a requirement to have a visible focus rectangle for an element that has focus in order to satisfy WCAG 2 (see [guideline 2.4.7: Focus Visible](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/focus-visible.html)).

I tested both card examples with JAWS 2022 and it correctly announced the link in either case.

On a side note, the colour contrast ratio of the blue link text against the green background is [too low to satisfy WCAG 2](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/contrast-minimum.html), so you'll need to increase the contrast ratio to at least 4.5:1 to make it accessible. I'm sure it's just that way right now for the example but thought it's worth a mention since you're asking about accessibility.

Comment: Thanks for testing this out, George - I really appreciate it (downloading this JAWS thing myself)

Yes, the green/blue colors was just for the example, but great mention about the contrast ratio!

Comment: @FrankBlue Definitely a good idea to test your website with screen readers. JAWS has a 40 minute free use period, after which you'll need to restart your machine to continue testing. NVDA is a free and open source alternative that's also widely used.

Answer (score 0):

As with everything it depends on your needs.  In the end you just want a link to fill an area.  It need not even be `absolute`. It's all a matter of preference.

```css
.card {
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.absolute-a, .absolute-span {
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

a.alt {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px dashed yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <a href="#" class="absolute-a">
    Using absolute on anchor
  </a>
</div> 

<div class="card">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="absolute-span">
      Using absolute span
    </span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="card">
 <a class="alt" href="#">Hi</a>
</div>
```